# Sharing text with a contentURL to Google Plus does not populate text field

Tags: android, url, google-plus

This code comes directly from Google at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/

```
  // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
  Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
      .setType("text/plain")
      .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
      .getIntent();

  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

The problem is the text won't populate the text field in the shareIntent although the Google developers link will show up.

Commenting out the setContentURL line as follows will then let the text field populate, however, the Google developers link then does not show up as expected.

```
  // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
  Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
      .setType("text/plain")
      .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
  //  .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
      .getIntent();

  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: Which version of Google Play services are you using? Can you try updating to the latest (4.2) if you're not on it?

Comment: FWIW, I was having the same problem. Ian Barber's solution to upgrade the play services to 4.2 (4.2.42) worked!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not work for me. My GS4 is at version 4.2.43 for Google Play services and I just updated my HTC to 4.2.43 as well and I am still having the same issue on both devices. I also just updated Google+ to the newest version, 4.2.4.58179886. I will try updating my sdk and see if that could be it.

Comment: Updating the Google Play Services SDK did not work either.

Comment: Waiting for someone to answer this :/